# Stella Architect - System Dynamics - resetting smooth and delay functions

Tags: dynamic, stock

I would love your technical advice: In the simplified example attached (https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/qhfDnUAdnYw6wxs - EDU link), I wish to reset the values in the smooth and delay functions to their initial values every 52 weeks (430 and 50 respectively). Indeed, in my more complex model, I wish to reset all the model’s values and parameters on a regular basis.
Would you mind helping me with that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used COUNTER to track when to reset to the initial value. See below:
[image]

Converter 3: SMTH3(Stock_3, 10, 430)

smthstock3: IF Converter_2 > 0 THEN SMTH3(Stock_3, 10, 430) ELSE INIT(Converter_3)

Converter 2: COUNTER(0, 52)